# Is it safe to add a new node to a Cassandra cluster while a repair is running?

Tags: clustering, cassandra

I'm getting ready to expand an existing Cassandra cluster.  I have repairs scheduled to run on a reoccurring basis.  Do I need to disable repairs when adding a new node to a cluster, or can I bootstrap new nodes while repairs are running elsewhere in the cluster?

Comment: from what I see [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesTOC.html), there is no restriction, so you can add a node to the cluster at the time when rebuild runs. Personally, I would try to exclude  
crossing such operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Datastax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesTOC.html),

> Warning: DataStax **recommends stopping repair operations during topology changes**; the Repair Service does this automatically. Repairs running during a topology change are likely to error when it involves moving ranges.

So, it is clear that topology changes (adding/removing nodes) are not recommended when there is a repair process alive in your cluster

Comment: That's a new blurb added to that document after this question was posted. It wasn't so clear back then. Additionally, it doesn't say that it's unsafe to do so, just that repairs will fail when ranges are moved.  However being that this is the only answer I've received since asking this question two years ago and it's a decent answer I've accepted it.